# React/Redux mapStateToProps "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

Step 1. I am creating a Redux store to get the test data.

```js
export default [
  {
    icon: 'cubes',
    timestamp: '2323424',
    title: 'ship load',
    rfid: 'arizona',
    type: 'Order Created',
    notes: 'children on board',
    iconColor: '#ff6718',
    txHash: '0x12312415254254253453453',
  },
  {
    icon: 'bus',
    timestamp: '320032424',
    title: 'board bus',
    rfid: 'cali',
    notes: 'large item with odd dimensions',
    iconColor: '#ff6718',
    txHash: '0x12312415254254253453453',
  }
]
```

Step 2. I am calling this file in log.js page as.

```js
import { List } from 'immutable';
import testData from './testData';

const initialState = List(testData);

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Step 3. I am calling this Log.js in my UI page using mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    Log: state.Log.toJSON(),
});
```

I keep getting error here. I am using immutable.js `LIST()` to get the data array. I tried `toJS()` anyway getting this `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined"` error.

Comment: Please provide more context info, e.g. what's in log.js?

Comment: the directory is /redux//Log/Log.js . The testdata,js is also in the same folder /Log. The mapStateToProps I am trying call from UI directory /src/page/eventLog.js

Comment: Yes, but what's inside those files?

Comment: `import { List } from 'immutable';
import testData from './testData';

const initialState = List(testData);

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
`

Comment: Please add it to the original question :)

Comment: let me see if I have editing privileges. lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163009/discussion-between-lukasz-godziejewski-and-user5313842).